# swap the Multiple Video Html elements before Removing

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

**how to swap the elements before Removing them without the use of a clone using jquery**

*I created the video call app for using picture in picture mode that was working properly but I have a small issue when I click to swap the video that working properly, after swapping when I want to remove some video they are not working properly.*

*JsFile*

```
/* swaping the videoElement */
function initVideoSwapping() {

    // check if there is an element first
    if ($('.video-list .videoWrap').length > 0 && $('.mainVideo').length > 0) {
        $('.video-list .videoWrap').on('click', function () {
            /* stopEvent Propogation */
            var $this = $(this);
            console.log($this)
            $this.data('clicked', true);
            initRemoveSwap()
            var IsadminTrue = getDataFromQueryString()
            if (IsadminTrue.isadmin) {
                var $StopthisDrop = $(this).find('#DropDown')[0];
                $StopthisDrop.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation()
                })
                var $StopthisBtn = $(this).find('button')[0];
                $StopthisBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation()
                })
            }
          
            // name
            var $thisName = $(this).find('span')[0]
            var $mainName = $('.main-videoWrap').find('span')[0]
            // dropdown
            var $thisBtn = $(this).find('button')[0];
            var $mainbtn = $('.main-videoWrap').find('button')[0];
            var $thisUlElement = $(this).find('ul')[0];
            var $mainUlElement = $('.main-videoWrap').find('ul')[0];
            // video
            var $thisVideo = $(this).find('video')[0];
            var $mainVideo = $('.main-videoWrap').find('video')[0];
            swapNodes($thisVideo, $mainVideo, $thisName, $mainName, $thisBtn, $mainbtn, IsadminTrue, $thisUlElement, $mainUlElement);
        });

    }
}

function swapNodes(thisVideo, mainVideo, thisName, mainName, thisBtn, mainbtn, thisUlelement, mainUlElement) {
    var thisVideoparent = thisVideo.parentNode;
    var asibling = thisVideo.nextSibling === mainVideo ? thisVideo : thisVideo.nextSibling;
    mainVideo.parentNode.insertBefore(thisVideo, mainVideo);
    thisVideoparent.insertBefore(mainVideo, asibling);

    // Name Change
    var thisNameParent = thisName.parentNode;
    var Namesiblings = thisName.nextSibling === mainName ? thisName : thisName.nextSibling;
    mainName.parentNode.insertBefore(thisName, mainName);
    thisNameParent.insertBefore(mainName, Namesiblings);

    // dropdown change
   
        var BtnParanet = thisBtn.parentNode;
        var Btniblings = thisBtn.nextSibling === mainbtn ? thisBtn : thisBtn.nextSibling;
        mainbtn.parentNode.insertBefore(thisBtn, mainbtn);
        BtnParanet.insertBefore(mainbtn, Btniblings);
        // ulElement Change
        var UlParanet = thisUlelement.parentNode;
        var ULSiblings = thisUlelement.nextSibling === mainUlElement ? thisUlelement : thisUlelement.nextSibling;
        mainUlElement.parentNode.insertBefore(thisUlelement, mainUlElement);
        UlParanet.insertBefore(mainUlElement, ULSiblings);
    

}

    var asibling = thisVideo.nextSibling === mainVideo ? thisVideo : thisVideo.nextSibling;
    mainVideo.parentNode.insertBefore(thisVideo, mainVideo);
    thisVideoparent.insertBefore(mainVideo, asibling);
    // Name Change
    var thisNameParent = thisName.parentNode;
    var Namesiblings = thisName.nextSibling === mainName ? thisName : thisName.nextSibling;
    mainName.parentNode.insertBefore(thisName, mainName);
    thisNameParent.insertBefore(mainName, Namesiblings);
    // if (IsadminTrue.isadmin) {
    var BtnParanet = thisBtn.parentNode;
    var Btniblings = thisBtn.nextSibling === mainbtn ? thisBtn : thisBtn.nextSibling;
    mainbtn.parentNode.insertBefore(thisBtn, mainbtn);
    BtnParanet.insertBefore(mainbtn, Btniblings);
    // ulElement Change
    var UlParanet = thisUlelement.parentNode;
    var ULSiblings = thisUlelement.nextSibling === mainUlElement ? thisUlelement : thisUlelement.nextSibling;
    mainUlElement.parentNode.insertBefore(thisUlelement, mainUlElement);
    UlParanet.insertBefore(mainUlElement, ULSiblings);
    // }
}}
```

*My Last Try was*

```
function initRemoveSwap() {
    var IsadminTrue = getDataFromQueryString()
    if (IsadminTrue.isadmin) {
        $('.video-list .videoWrap').on('remove', function () {
            var $thisVideo = $(this).find('video')[0];
            var $mainVideo = $('.main-videoWrap').find('video')[0];
            // name
            var $thisName = $(this).find('span')[0]
            var $mainName = $('.main-videoWrap').find('span')[0]
            // dropdown
            var $thisBtn = $(this).find('button')[0];
            var $mainbtn = $('.main-videoWrap').find('button')[0];

            var $thisUlElement = $(this).find('ul')[0];
            var $mainUlElement = $('.main-videoWrap').find('ul')[0];

            RemoveswapNodes($mainVideo, $thisVideo, $thisName, $mainName, $thisBtn, $mainbtn, IsadminTrue, $thisUlElement, $mainUlElement);

        })

    }
function RemoveswapNodes(mainVideo, thisVideo, thisName, mainName, thisBtn, mainbtn, IsadminTrue, thisUlelement, mainUlElement) {
        // videoChange
        var thisVideoparent = thisVideo.parentNode;
        var asibling = thisVideo.nextSibling === mainVideo ? thisVideo : thisVideo.nextSibling;
        mainVideo.parentNode.insertBefore(thisVideo, mainVideo);
        thisVideoparent.insertBefore(mainVideo, asibling);
        // Name Change
        var thisNameParent = thisName.parentNode;
        var Namesiblings = thisName.nextSibling === mainName ? thisName : thisName.nextSibling;
        mainName.parentNode.insertBefore(thisName, mainName);
        thisNameParent.insertBefore(mainName, Namesiblings);
        // if (IsadminTrue.isadmin) {
        var BtnParanet = thisBtn.parentNode;
        var Btniblings = thisBtn.nextSibling === mainbtn ? thisBtn : thisBtn.nextSibling;
        mainbtn.parentNode.insertBefore(thisBtn, mainbtn);
        BtnParanet.insertBefore(mainbtn, Btniblings);
        // ulElement Change
        var UlParanet = thisUlelement.parentNode;
        var ULSiblings = thisUlelement.nextSibling === mainUlElement ? thisUlelement : thisUlelement.nextSibling;
        mainUlElement.parentNode.insertBefore(thisUlelement, mainUlElement);
        UlParanet.insertBefore(mainUlElement, ULSiblings);
        // }
    }
}


window.addEventListener('click', initVideoSwapping, false)
```

I've tried a lot of different ways to change items. I've tried with replaceWith(), before(), and after() but nothing worked.

NOTE: I've already written a function which displays the correct up / down DIVs. So the first and last one can only moved in one direction. That's already solved. I also can't use any kind of existing jQuery plugins.

Kindly Help to how to solve this issue!